# Post-build event command line: xcopy ERROR

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I'm having problem with deploying my project through post build event, so basically Im copying my src codes to my Artifacts/Slam/src, so everytime it builds the project it copies the same project to Artifacts. I have no problem with my main project because I am able to successfully build it, but when i open the project from artifacts folder, its giving me this error `The command "xcopy D:\nera-sdk\Artifacts\Slam\src\samples\Slam D:\nera-sdk\Artifacts\Slam\src\Artifacts\Slam\src\ /y /s" exited with code 4.` what can i do with this. Someone please help me. thanks!

and here is how i command it:

```
xcopy $(SolutionDir)samples\Slam $(SolutionDir)Artifacts\Slam\src\ /y /s
```

Comment: anyone that can help me?

Comment: You need to give the full error message (it will be in the build log, but you might need to turn up the detail level).